# How to make threads execute based on counters on Jmeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter, automated-tests

I have 4 different thread groups, let's call them testA, testB, testC, and testD.

testA has 100 loops or it could be infinite. I need testB to execute on every 3rd loop from testA and testC to execute on every 10th loop from testA.

I have counters to count the number of loops under each test. How would I go with doing this? Do I put an If Controller above each test? If so, what do I put on each if controller, or is there a better way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to put If Controller in `testA` only. When it comes to "what to put" - I would go for [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

- `${__groovy(vars.getIteration() % 3 == 0,)}`  - for executing each 3rd loop
- `${__groovy(vars.getIteration() % 10 == 0,)}` - for executing each 10th loop

Now the question is what to put under the If Controller, if you want sequential execution - go for [Module Controller](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421345-Using-JMeter-Module-Controller) which will call the Samplers from testB, if you want parallel execution - go for [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/)